# haproxy 2.2.x - acl url_reg wont work anymore

Tags: haproxy, regex

I try to udate from haproxy 1.8.25 to 2.2.9. Everything is fine so far, but all may acl for url filtering to route some traffic to diffrent backends wont work anymore.

Example:

this request https://www.foo.bar/images/charts/test.png shoud be go to backend "Backend-Charts"

```
    acl is_charts url_reg ^\/images/charts/.*
    use_backend Backend-Charts if is_charts
```

But the logfile shows me that this traffic still goes to the default backend. But with haproxy 1.8.25 this works perfekt.

Im not sure where is my mistake and I would appreciate any help.

All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Solution: use_backend Backend-Charts if { path_beg /images/charts/ }